# Como fazer um regex que aceita 8 ou 9 dígitos com DDD de 2 dígitos?

Tags: regex

Eu tenho código de pattern: `^[1-9]{2}9?[0-9]{8}$`, então mudei de ideia de fazer com regex com mascara e tal...

Exemplo:

- (11) 1111-1111 - `fixo válido`
- (11) 11111-1111 - `celular inválido`
- (11) 91111-1111 - `celular válido`
- (11) 01111-1111 - `celular inválido`

Formato: DDD de 2 caracteres (9º dígito é opcional). Se começar com 9 dígitos, deve começar com número 9.

Como posso fazer isso em regex ?

Segue regex pronta que eu não consegui fazer: https://regex101.com/r/ZBxjSs/1

Comment: Basta remover `,5` do seu regex.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, Pode crê, era só remover `,5` já resolve o problema.

Comment: @danieltakeshi, seu regex permite digitar mais de 9 dígitos

Comment: Meu Regex era basicamente igual ao seu corrigido, só que aceitava de zero a infinitos espaços. Mas como o Valdeir falou, era só tirar o `,5`... `\(?\d{2}\)?\s?9?\d{4}-?\d{4}`. FWIW: Para um valor como `(12 1111-1111` também é aceito, mas são erros de digitação que você pode contornar com outros tipos de programação.

Answer (score 5):

Seguindo exatamente a regra do post, segue o passo a passo:

- \( = Caracter (, caso contrário teríamos um grupo
- \d = Dígito qualquer
- {2} = repetição
- \) = Caracter ), caso contrário teríamos um fechamento de grupo
- \s = Espaço
- 9? = Caracter 9, a interrogação serve para dizer que ele é opcional

> \(\d{2})\s9?\d{4}-\d{4}

[Exemplo para sua dúvida](https://regex101.com/r/ZBxjSs/2)

edit: Não existe ddd que inicia com 0, então a expressão deveria ser diferente:

> \([1-9]\d\)\s9?\d{4}-\d{4}

[Exemplo validando melhor o DDD](https://regex101.com/r/ZBxjSs/3)